# How to show the continuity of the following operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, compact-operators

Let $T:\mathcal{l}^2\to\mathcal{l}^2$ be an operator with

$$(Tu)_n:= \frac{1}{2}u_n + \frac{1}{n^2}u_n.$$

I've found that the operator is **not** compact, since

$$(Tu)_n = \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)u_n$$

consists a sequence which converges not to zero. But how can I show whether the operator is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u^{(k)} \to u$ and $Tu^{(k)} \to v$ in $\ell^2$. Then, for all $n\geq 1$,
\begin{align}
|(Tu)_n-v_n|&\leq |(Tu)_n - (Tu^{(k)})_n|+|(Tu^{(k)})_n-v_n|\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)|u_n-u^{(k)}_n|+|(Tu^{(k)})_n-v_n|\\
&\leq \frac{3}{2}\Vert u-u^{(k)} \Vert_2 + \Vert Tu^{(k)}-v \Vert_2 \to 0,
\end{align}
as $k\to\infty$,
so $(Tu)_n = v_n$ for each $n\geq 1$, and thus $Tu=v$.
The Closed graph theorem does the rest.

Alternatively, observe that
$$ \Vert Tu \Vert_2^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2 |u_n|^2 \leq \frac{9}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n|^2 = \frac{9}{4} \Vert u\Vert_2^2. $$